# Symfony2 Fatal error in Users Entity Provider

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using symfony 2.3.4 and in security configuration I want to to load Security Users from the Database accordingly to this [Cookbook instruction](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html). But I only get this error:

> Fatal error: Class MyApp\AdminBundle\Entity\Users contains 3 abstract
>   methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the
>   remaining methods
>   (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getRoles,
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getUsername,
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::eraseCredentials)
>   in /Volumes/Htdocs/symfony/src/MyApp/AdminBundle/Entity/Users.php

Comment: Can you post the code of the Users class?? It seems you did not implement the three methods which are defined by the "UserInterface" interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symfony's security framework expects the User entity to implement the `UserInterface`. Implement the three methods:

```
public function getRoles()
public function getUsername()
public function eraseCredentials()
```

Comment: I don't see a user interface at all. Should that be implemented manually or it can be auto generated ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the methods from the interface. ;)